# Conditionally extract to a list variable values that appear in all columns

Tags: r

Given the sample data `sampleDT` below, I would appreciate any help to create a function that allows me to conditionally extract to a list without repetition the variable values that appear in all columns - at least appear once in each of the columns regardless of the position.

```
# sample data
sampleDT<-structure(list(V2 = c(5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15), 
    V3 = c(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 2), .indices = c(6, 
    7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16), .indices3 = c(1, 2, 
    3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Reduce(f = intersect, x = sampleDT)
[1]  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

Use the `intersect` set operation on all the columns.

`Reduce` is a nice way to write `intersect(intersect(sampleDT[[1]], sampleDT[[2]]), sampleDT[[3]]), ...))`

Comment: Great, @Gregor. Thanks for this very helpful and beautiful solution.